# PHP pass variables from one loop to another and sorting outside the loop

Tags: php

First I have a loop that displays a given users friend list.

```
$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT friend1, friend2 
                    FROM list_friends 
                    WHERE (friend1 = :user AND friend2 <> :user) 
                    OR (friend2 = :user AND friend1 <> :user)');

$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll()
foreach  ($row AS $row) {
    if ($row[friend1] !== $username) {
        $friend = $row[friend1]; 
    } else {
        $friend = $row[friend2]; 
    }
    echo $friend;
}
```

Second I have a series of arrays being compared and sorted by time and date, then echo'd

```
$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM banners WHERE username = :user');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $friend);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE username = :user');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $friend);
$stmt->execute();
$row1 = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM sites WHERE username = :user');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $friend);
$stmt->execute();
$row2 = $stmt->fetchAll();

$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM social_posts WHERE username = :user');
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $friend);
$stmt->execute();
$row3 = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($db2->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'elfinder_file_".strtolower($friend)."'"
           )->rowCount() > 0
){
$stmt=$db2->prepare("SELECT * FROM elfinder_file_".strtolower($friend)." WHERE mime <> 'directory' GROUP BY time");
$stmt->execute();
$row4 = $stmt->fetchAll();
}


foreach( $row AS $banner_table ) {
    $data[] = array('type' => 'banner', 'time' => $banner_table["time"]);
}
foreach( $row1 AS $favorites_table ) {
    $data[] = array('type' => 'favorite', 'time' => $favorites_table["time"]);
}
foreach( $row2 AS $sites_table ) {
    $data[] = array('type' => 'sites', 'time' => $sites_table["time"], 'site' => $sites_table["url"], 'title' => $sites_table["title"]);
}
foreach( $row3 AS $social_table ) {
    $data[] = array('type' => 'social', 'time' => $social_table["time"], 'thetype' => $social_table["type"]);
}

if ($db2->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'elfinder_file_".strtolower($_GET[user])."'")->rowCount() > 0 )
{
    foreach( $row4 AS $photos_table ) {
        $data[] = array('type' => 'photo', 'time' => $photos_table["time"]);
    }
}

function cmp($a, $b)  {
    $ad = new DateTime($a['time']);
    $bd = new DateTime($b['time']);   
    if ($ad == $bd) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $ad < $bd ? -1 : 1;
}
if ($data !== NULL) {
    usort($data, "cmp");
    for($i=(count($data)-1);$i>=0;$i--){
        $tttime = $data[$i]['time'];
        $ttime = new DateTime($tttime);
        $stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT timezone FROM member_credits WHERE username = :user');
        $stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if ($row[timezone] === NULL) { $row[timezone] = 'America/Denver'; }
        $usersTimezone = (new DateTimeZone($row[timezone]));
        $ttime->setTimeZone($usersTimezone);
        $ttimee = $ttime->format('D M j, Y g:i A');
        if($data[$i]['type']=='favorite'){
            echo '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' added a website to their favorites while surfing the exchange.</li>';
        } elseif($data[$i]['type']=='banner'){
            echo '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' added a banner to the banner exchange.</li>';  
        } elseif($data[$i]['type']=='sites'){
            echo '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' added the website &nbsp;<a href="'.$data[$i]['site'].'" target="_blank" style="font-weight:bolder;">'.$data[$i]['title'].'</a>&nbsp; to the traffic exchange.</li>';  
        } elseif($data[$i]['type']=='social'){
            echo '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' has requested a social exchange on '.$data[$i]['thetype'].'.</li>';  
        } elseif($data[$i]['type']=='photo'){
            echo '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' uploaded a photo to their profile.</li>';  
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that if I do the first foreach, then the second, it only echo's results from the last friend in the loop (logically), and if I contain the second foreach inside the first, it generates all results for each user one by one, so all of user1's results will be returned and sorted by time, then all of user2's, and so on.

The result I am looking for, is a list of results all joined together, and then each returned based on time.

**SAMPLE RESULTS:**

```
user1 uploaded a photo at 12:00pm
user2 added a banner at 11:00 am
user2 uploaded a photo at 10:00 am
user1 added a favorite 9:00 am
etc.
etc.
etc.
```

Comment: This is a very different question from what you originally asked and I just answered in details.

Comment: $friend is undefined. timezone is also undefined in your code. have you defined it define('timezone', ''); ?Or should be $row['timezone']. $_GET[user] is also undefined shouldnt be $_GET['user'] ?

Comment: @AndrásSzepesházi yes it is very different, for the reasons I noted in reply to your answer.

Comment: @iiro timezone is defined:  if ($row[timezone] === NULL) { $row[timezone] = 'America/Denver'; } $usersTimezone = (new DateTimeZone($row[timezone])); No friend is not defined, thats the point. I can't figure out how to properly define it as I have with the other selects, as its not a table column name, its a table name.

Comment: @Bruce no, the term timezone is not defined.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "the term" is not defined. The timezone code works flawlessly. If the user has no timezone set it defaults to America/Denver. Otherwise its whatever the user has set.

Comment: Please do not change the question. Ask a new one instead

Comment: @Bruce here is a hint:
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant timezone - assumed 'timezone' in /t.php on line 3
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: row in /t.php on line 3
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant timezone - assumed 'timezone' in /t.php on line 3

and the t.php is:
if ($row[timezone] === NULL) { $row[timezone] = 'America/Denver'; }

TL;DR: your code is broken.

Comment: SO as I understood it says I am suppose to update my code and questions to reflect and show I am actively working on a problem and to show updates. Effectively what you are telling me is if I ask a question on SO (note I asked this 2+ hours before an answer) I should basically just ignore it, never come back to it, and ask a new question.... or not work on the code that brought me to the question. Obviously if my question is not answered in a few minutes, I am going to keep attempting to solve it myself, and thus, keep updating both code and question as I get further along.

Comment: @iiro I have no idea what you are doing, what you are getting at, nor why you are bringing this up when I have said my timezone code has no errors at all. Do you also think my code should have errors because I don't show my database connections in my code? Or any of my includes?

Comment: @Bruce oh sorry. I'd like to try my code myself if you would show the full code. That is why i'm asking.

Comment: @iiro its not so easy to do, as the code has countless includes and countless variabl s set on other pages. If it helps there is in a file includes/func.php called on every page the following: date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver'); // your reference timezone here

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing the results, use an array with the time as an index. Gather all your results and sort the array by the index. Something along the lines of

```
$li[$ttimee] .= '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' uploaded a photo to their profile.</li>';
```

I use `.=` so things happening at the same time are not overitten.

Comment: I updated the question a bit to help make it clearer. The problem isn't with the actual loops or echo's, there are a number of ways to do that. The problem is getting the data to correctly return. I should probably edit and add the tag sql as it now relates more to my select statement then it does the loops.

Comment: What I suggest is to gather all results, regardless of user in one array, instead of echoing directly inside the loop. Echoing will either gather all users or all actions together. Gather all actions of all the users in a sortable array, which has the time as index. This way you can have all the actions sorted

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops: within the first loop that queries the list of friends, place all the code for getting various activities by each of those friends, and add those activities to a single array. Then you can sort all results by timestamps.

Also, in your code the `$row` variable name is reused several times for different purposes; you'll lose information that you want to hold on to. As a general rule, always use meaningful variable names for the sake of your fellow programmers and yourself. `$tttime`, `$ttime` and `$ttimee` are not really friendly for the reader.

So the code should be something along the lines of (haven't tested it):

```
function cmp($a, $b)  {
    $ad = new DateTime($a['time']);
    $bd = new DateTime($b['time']);   
    if ($ad == $bd) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $ad < $bd ? -1 : 1;
}

$all_activies = [];
$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT friend1, friend2 
                    FROM list_friends 
                    WHERE (friend1 = :user AND friend2 <> :user) 
                    OR (friend2 = :user AND friend1 <> :user)');

$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$friends = $stmt->fetchAll()

foreach  ($row AS $friends) {
    if ($row[friend1] !== $username) {
        $friend = $row[friend1]; 
    } else {
        $friend = $row[friend2]; 
    }

    /* repeat this block for each activity type */
    $stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM banners WHERE username = :user');
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $friend);
    $stmt->execute();
    $banners = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($banner AS $bannners ) {
        $all_activies[] = array('friend' => '$friend', 'type' => 'banner', 'time' => $banner["time"]);
    }
    /* repeat this block for each activity type */


}

if ($all_activies !== NULL) {
    usort($all_activies, "cmp");
    for($i=(count($all_activies)-1);$i>=0;$i--){
        $tttime = $all_activies[$i]['time'];
        $friend = $all_activies[$i]['friend']

        $ttime = new DateTime($tttime);
        $stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT timezone FROM member_credits WHERE username = :user');
        $stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if ($row[timezone] === NULL) { $row[timezone] = 'America/Denver'; }
        $usersTimezone = (new DateTimeZone($row[timezone]));
        $ttime->setTimeZone($usersTimezone);
        $ttimee = $ttime->format('D M j, Y g:i A');

        if($all_activies[$i]['type']=='favorite'){
            echo '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' added a website to their favorites while surfing the exchange.</li>';
        } elseif($all_activies[$i]['type']=='banner'){
            echo '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' added a banner to the banner exchange.</li>';  
        } elseif($all_activies[$i]['type']=='sites'){
            echo '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' added the website &nbsp;<a href="'.$all_activies[$i]['site'].'" target="_blank" style="font-weight:bolder;">'.$all_activies[$i]['title'].'</a>&nbsp; to the traffic exchange.</li>';  
        } elseif($all_activies[$i]['type']=='social'){
            echo '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' has requested a social exchange on '.$all_activies[$i]['thetype'].'.</li>';  
        } elseif($all_activies[$i]['type']=='photo'){
            echo '<li style="padding: 8px 5px 8px 95px;"><span class="date"><b>'.$ttimee.'</b></span>'.$friend.' uploaded a photo to their profile.</li>';  
        }
    }
}
```

You code still has several issues that do not reflect best practices. Querying the time zone for each activity, not limiting the result set for activities, etc. - these should all be addressed, especially if you'd like to put your code in production.

Comment: My original code was EXACTLY like this. Thats what originally brought me to ask questions. The problem with this code is, it ends up returning the results per user. So I get user1 echo'd sorted by time, then user2, then3, and it doesn't properly sort all users mixed together by time.

Comment: Have you even tried the above? You code was very different, actually.